# Are mounting screws standard with M.2 SSDs?

Tags: installation, screws, m.2

I'm looking at buying a 512gb, Samsung PM951 SSD from [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA2W04G10489&cm_re=pm951-_-0D9-0009-000W2-_-Product) and trying to figure out if I need to buy a mounting screw separately or if it comes included - Newegg doesn't seem to provide any details on what's included in the package, and there doesn't seem to be much information on whether or not it's standard to include mounting screws with an SSD in general. I did buy an mSATA card from Newegg a while back and I don't think it came with any mounting materials.

Do I need to order a mounting screw separately?

Comment: we cant know that for everything, but they should come with the motherboard itself, and i am sure that was mentioned more than once.

Comment: @Psycogeek the target system's a laptop (not bought yet), so I won't be provided with any of the materials that would accompany a standalone motherboard.

Comment: If the laptop already have its own m.2 SSD - you can just reuse the existing one?

Comment: @Darius good suggestion, but it'll arrive with only an HDD on a SATA port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've purchased a Samsung SM951. There is no screw coming with it.
Agree with @Psycogeek , my screw comes with the motherboard.(ASUS Z170-AR)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Good to know, also reminded me of the difference between PM951 and SM951.